# for loop runs only once with setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I found this codesnipe in a famous tool by greensock (SplitText)
Why is the for-loop only running once? In my opinion it must run three times (tt.length). Any explanation is welcome.

```js
var u = "undefined" != typeof window,
  tt = ["AAA", "BB", "CCC"],
  F = tt.length;

for (setTimeout(function checkWarn() {
    if (u)
      console.log("is u", F)
    else {
      console.log("is not u")
    }
  }, 50); - 1 < --F;);
```

Comment: How do you know how often the loop runs? The loop body is empty.

Comment: The loop runs three times, but the _initialization_ part of the `for` loop is visited only once at the beginning of the loop, hence only a single timer is set.

Comment: @hamburger — It's appallingly bad code and you won't learn anything good studying it.

Comment: it's clear the for loop runs 4 iterations since F is -1

Comment: @JaromandaX Nope, the first check before entering the loop recudes `F` by one, the loop runs only 3 rounds.

Comment: iterations: f=2, f=1, f=0, f=-1 @Teemu no?

Comment: @GrafiCode [When running](https://jsfiddle.net/xefctpj2/) then no. I stripped the crappy part of the code from the snippet, I hope I didn't mess anything.

Comment: @Teemu ah right, `- 1 < --F`  when == -1 it stops... thanks for the fiddle

Comment: @Teemu - correct (I knew I was off by one, story of my life)

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout` is part of the [initialization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#syntax) of the `for` loop declaration. This particular block is only run once.

Furthermore, `for(…);` is a "empty statement" loop which would rely entirely on side-effects in the `condition` and `afterthought` expressions.

The following is likely closer to what you need, albeit not exactly my cup of tea:

```
for (; -1 < --F;) {
  setTimeout(function checkWarn() {
    if (u)
      console.log("is u", F)
    else {
      console.log("is not u")
    }
  }, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout(...)` is (very oddly) placed inside the loop initializer part, where one would normally put more useful code like `let i = 0;`. The initializer part runs only once by definition.

The `setTimeout` then causes the function *inside* it to be excuted also exactly once, after a short delay. By that time the `for` loop has already finished running because it has decremented `F` until it became `-1` so that value is what the inner function then prints.